# what is the maximum number of pools with hadoop fair scheduler?

Tags: hadoop

What is the maximum number of pools with the hadoop 1 fair scheduler?

A [google search](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=hadoop%20fair%20scheduler%20maximum%20numbers%20of%20pools&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=6V-tUtXdBoSQtAbpwYD4DQ) and a look in the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/fair_scheduler.html) did not reveal anything.

Comment: I didn't know there is a maximum. What leads you to believe there is one?

Comment: I don't know. I am planning to use it in a project where i will have thousands of pools, so i don't want to get stuck afterwards. So i want to be sure that there is no limit

Answer (score 1):

Queues and Containers in the fair scheduler source are using Heap data structures, I couldn't find the Pool structure, my guess is that they are similar, IE just restricted by heap space.